# Can I use Parse's REST API Console to update objects that match a query?

Tags: parse-platform

I've added a new field to my Parse `_User` table. I'd like to update existing users that have that field set to `undefined` to `true`. I can query for those users through the API console:

```
classes/_User
where={"myNewField": null}
```

How can I update the field of the resulting users through the REST API console?

Comment: I am not sure how you want to do a query and a batch update at the same time

Comment: Me neither. I was hoping there was some equivalent of `.each()` available in the console. Is there?

Comment: Not really. There is no way to perform a REST request on the result of another on in one step

Comment: Feel free to make that an answer. Is the console just to test queries you'd be coding then? No way to bulk updates like you could on an SQL server?